How to Navigate and Scroll in IPython Notebook Efficiently
I have a degree in CS & have over 10 years of experience coding, but I am new to Python & Python Notebooks.  I am using Google Collab and the number #1 difficulty I have is navigating the UI. Scrolling up and down the blocks of code/text on the right side and the tree view on the left side.  I literally need to resize the window and then race to grab a scroll bar before it disappears.  Then I can only go so far and I have to start all over and do another resize. I would really appreciate hearing how others manage to move up and down the tree view and code sections with ease?   Do you run the collab notebook in a browser? But I have also experienced similar with notebooks even in Visual Studio Code with the plugin enabled.  I think notebooks could be awesome for productivity but frankly for me it has slowed me down by at least 50%.
Mostly resizing the window to get a scroll bar. I have tried navigating with arrow keys etc.  The only thing that works at all for me is resizing the window and grabbing the scroll bar.  But its very inefficient.   I am definitely not learning by using! I have been using it for a few weeks and its still not intuitive for me.
Update: Here is an example where usng up/down arrow keys do not work:  The keys will go this far down and no farther. If I want to see latest output,  I need to resize the window and scroll from the size unless there is a better way? I did check the documentation. Getting started guide etc and I dont see any advice on navigation.

just for for clarification. right now I am learning about mounting google drive in Collab and after loading it I want to do somethiing very simple like see if the file I uploaded is in the tree. Scrolling the left hand tree view seem very difficult. Again window resizing is the only way I am able to get to see the file.

And on the right hand side I have not figured out how to move gracefully from top to bottom or back up. Arrow keys do not seem to work for this.

I use vim, vi, eclipse, visual studio etc.  honestly its the only UI I have used except those for odeling  or drawing where its has taken me this long to move about

well I guess everyone except me thinks that Python notebooks work just fine on all browsers! Thanks for the feedback!
